# If A is symmetric and B > 0, A and B are both n x n, then PROVE that X^TAX / X^TBX lies between the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of B^-1A.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

So from my understanding, I got the following two steps but not sure if it works:

1. `X^TAX`has minimum value of λAn and maximum value of λA1. Similarly, `X^TBX`has minimum value of λBn and maximum value of λB1. So the minimum value of `X^TAX / X^TBX`is λAn/λB1, and its maximum value is λA1/λBn.
2. I can easily prove that the eigenvalues of `B^-1A` are the same to `AB^-1`.

From here I stuck and not sure how to proceed or if I had the right logic, so please help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For any vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$, let $x = B^{-1/2}y$.
$$
\frac{x^TAx}{x^TBx} = \frac{(B^{-1/2}y)^TA(B^{-1/2}y)}{(B^{-1/2}y)^T(B^{-1/2}y)} = \frac{y^TB^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}y}{y^Ty}.
$$